# When running ecryptfs-migrate-home -u USER I get command not found error

Tags: 11.10, ecryptfs, command-line

Just like in the title,

```
boywithaxe@Xerxes:~$ sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u test
[sudo] password for boywithaxe: 
sudo: ecryptfs-migrate-home: command not found
boywithaxe@Xerxes:~$
```

I realise this could be a very stupid question, but googling the string didn't return anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the `ecryptfs-utils`, do that using these commands on a terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

or look for `ecryptfs-utils` in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Don't forget your should not run `sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home` for a user currently in logged in.

Comment: That did it! I tried
    sudo apt-get install ecryptfs
and that didn't find anything. I assumed it would have been included with the install, seeing the user is asked to encrypt straight after the install. Regardless, thank you very much that helped :)

Comment: FWIW, to search for applications (on the command line) try `apt-cache search ecryptfs`

Comment: @boywithaxe when trying to figure out what packages you need but you do not know exactly the name you can also press tab to auto complete the same you do with a command on a terminal or auto complete for a path.